# Zend Framework 2 - translate form errors with variable

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translation, intl

I work on a multilingual web application with ZF2 (2.2.6).

I've installed php5-intl and enabled it in the php.ini

I've add this on my module config :

```
array(
    'type'        => 'phparray',
    'base_dir'    =>  'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages',
    'pattern'     => '/fr/Zend_Validate.php',
    'text_domain' => 'default'
    )
```

The translation work on simple message like "Value is required and can't be empty" but don't work if the text contains parameters like "The input is less than 3 characters long".

Answer (score 0):

You have to translate the exact string as it is written in the validator itself. The `3` is substituted. If you [look at the source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/StringLength.php#L25-L27), you see there's another string.

TL;DR: translate `The input is less than %min% characters long`

Comment: Thank you, but i don't need to translate the text by myself. I just want to use the resources Zend_Validate.php, which contain pre-translated string.

Comment: Oh damn, missed that part completely. Not sure then. as I never use the provided resource files :)

Comment: @Badbugs you can debug yourself by checking variables inside the AbstractValidator class. Check error(), createMessage() and translateMessage(). Perhaps there's some issue in translating messages with variables from the resource file?